# How to update two tables using jpa with java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I  have a service that must update two tables named **Ajustes**  and **Valores**

[image]

I have my next class where I get the 2 parameters that I want to update

```html
public class ClasePruebaImpl{
     @Setter
     private PruebaOperacion pruebaOperacion;
     
     public void actualizar(final ClaseEntrada){
     
        pruebaOperacion.operacionActualizar(claseEntrada.getComponente(), claseEntrada.getModulo());
     }
     
}
```

and the class that the update logic should perform, where **Ajustes** and **Valores**  ​​are the Entity classes, which are already mapped but I don't know how to update

Someone help me how to do this,
which methods should I use?

```html
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PruebaOperacion{

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "USER_PU")
  private EntityManager entityManager;
 
  @Interceptors(CheckpointMonitor.class)
  public void operacionActualizar(Integer componente, Integer modulo){
  
    //Entidades
    final Ajustes ajustes = new Ajustes();
    final Valores valores = new Valores();
  
  }
 
}
```

This is a query of how I implement the update

```html
UPDATE USER_PU.AJUSTES SET VALOR = 'Nuevo valoe 99'
WHERE TIPO = 'NEW' AND LLAVE= 'PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A';

UPDATE USER_PU.VALORES SET VALOR= '99'
WHERE ID_AJUSTE = (SELECT ID_AJUSTE FROM USER_PU.AJUSTES WHERE TIPO = 'NEW' AND LLAVE = 'PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways, the simplest would be with a @NamtiveQuery, but in my point of view the worst because it breaks with the JPA philosophy, the second with the entity manager obtaining and updating the entity and the third with the bulk operations.

1.- Native Query

```
Query q1= entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                " UPDATE USER_PU.AJUSTES SET VALOR = :nuevoValor1"+ 
                " WHERE TIPO = :tipo1 AND LLAVE= :llave1;");

q1.setParameter("nuevoValor1", "Nuevo valoe 99");
q1.setParameter("tipo1", "NEW");
q1.setParameter("llave1", "PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A");
q1.executeUpdate();
```

2.- Find Object and Update

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Ajustes> cq = cb.createQuery(Ajustes.class);
Root<Ajustes> rootAjustes = cq.from(Ajustes.class);

cq.where(
    cb.and(cb.equal(rootAjustes.get(Ajustes_.tipo),"NEW"),
        cb.equal(rootAjustes.get(Ajustes_.llave),"PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A")));

//BBDD entity
Ajustes resultado = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
//Update fields
resultado.setValor("nuevoValor1");
//Persist changes
entityManager.merge(resultado);
```

3.- Bulk Operation (new in JPA 2.1)

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Ajustes> cu = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Ajustes.class);
Root<Ajustes> rootAjustes = cu.from(Ajustes.class);

cu.set(rootAjustes.get(Ajustes_.valor), "Nuevo valoe 99");

cu.where(
    cb.and(cb.equal(rootAjustes.get(Ajustes_.tipo),"NEW"),
        cb.equal(rootAjustes.get(Ajustes_.llave),"PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A")));

return entityManager.createQuery(cu).executeUpdate();
```